# Sending an email in Iron Python taking forever

Tags: python, email, smtplib

So I'm trying to send an email in Iron Python 2.7, and nothing has worked for me. So I combined a bunch of different bits of code I got to try and workaround my issue. Basically, I need to send a zip file without using `localhost` because I'm assuming the client computer won't have localhost.

Here is my code:

```
# Send an email
def sendEmail():

    # Set standard variables
    send_to = ["*******@live.com"]
    send_from = "********@outlook.com"
    subject   = "New Game Info"
    text      = "Some new info for you. This is an automated message."

    assert isinstance(send_to, list)

    msg = MIMEMultipart(
        From=send_from,
        To=COMMASPACE.join(send_to),
        Date=formatdate(localtime=True),
        Subject=subject
    )

    print "Created MIME..."

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    print "Attached message..."

    with open("TempLog.zip", "rb") as fil:
        msg.attach(MIMEApplication(
            fil.read(),
            Content_Disposition='attachment; filename="%s"' % "TempLog.zip"
        ))

    print "Attached file..."

    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("*********@outlook.com", "*****")
    server.sendmail("********@outlook.com", send_to, msg.as_string())
    server.close()
```

So as you can see, I have put print statements everywhere to locate the issue. It gets up to "Attached file...," but no further.

I appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: What did your packet sniffer reveal?

Comment: I never checked using a packet sniffer, I might try that later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), a package that tries to make it really easy to send emails.

Maybe you can try this:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(send_from, password, host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com')
yag.send(send_to, subject = subject, contents = [text, "TempLog.zip"])
```

This should automatically have "text" as body, and when you give it the location of `TempLog.zip`, it will automatically detect it is a zip file and attach it.

You might have to install it:

```
pip install yagmail  # Python 2
pip3 install yagmail # Python 3
```

If something does not work (or when it does), please **let me know**! I will certainly try to help more.

Comment: I could use a tad bit of help... How do I use pip?

Comment: If you use a unix system you can just install pip, and then use the command to install. It's the package manager for python.

Comment: I don't know why but tessting yagmail it's taking so much time without giving out any errors or sending the actual email , do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `try/catch` block to figure out what the problem really is.

With your current code:

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP()
    server.connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("*********@outlook.com", "*****")
    server.sendmail("********@outlook.com", send_to, msg.as_string())
    server.close()
except SMTPException, err:
   print "ERROR: Unable to send mail - %s" %(err)
except Exception, err:
   print "Some other error - %s" %(err)
```

And for an example that I would suggest putting your host options in the SMTP initialization instead of doing so in `connect()`. You can modify this example to utilize `starttls()` as you need.

```
try:
  smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
  smtp.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
  print "Successfully sent email to '%s'" %(receivers)
except SMTPException, err:
  print "ERROR: Unable to send mail - %s" %(err)
except Exception, err:
   print "Some other error - %s" %(err)
```